# Smoothing curve for matplotlib.pyplot using pandas or numpy/scipy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a series of data which consists of values from several experiments (1-40, in the MWE it is 1-5). The overall amount of entries in my original data is ~4.000.000, which I try to smooth in order to display it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import spline
from statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess import lowess

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["values"] = np.random.randint(100000, 200000, 1000)
df["id"] = [1,2,3,4,5] * 200
plt.figure(1, figsize=(11.69,8.27))
# Both fail for my amount of data:
plt.plot(spline(df["values"], df["id"], range(100)), "r-")
plt.plot(lowess(df["values"], df["id"]), "r-")
```

Both, scipy.interplate and statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess, throw out of memory exceptions for my data. Is there any efficient way to solve this like in, e.g., GNU R using ggplot2 and geom_smooth()?

Comment: why you do `range(100)` in the first plot? In that place is an int.

Comment: According to the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.spline.html) it is a list/array of new x-values, which would be [0, 2, ..., 99] in that case, right?

Comment: Separate the smoothing computation from the plot call, so you see where it fails. My guess is that creating a plot with 4 million points is not very informative, and might require a large amount of memory. Also for lowess, the fraction to be used in the local regression should be reduced when the sample size is so large.

Comment: An uninformative plot is the reason why I wanted to change from plotting all values to smoothing. It fails on creating the smoothing computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite tell what you're getting at with all the dimensions to your data, but one very simple thing you can try is to just use the 'markevery' kwarg like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(1,100,1E7)
y=x**2
plt.figure(1, figsize=(11.69,8.27))
plt.plot(x,y,markevery=100)
plt.show()
```

This will only plot every nth point (n=100 here).

If that doesn't help then you may want to try just a simple numpy interpolation with fewer samples like so:

```
x_large=np.linspace(1,100,1E7)
y_large=x**2
x_small=np.linspace(1,100,1E3)
y_small=np.interp(x_small,x_large,y_large)
plt.plot(x_small,y_small)
```